# jwt token is not working with custom user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Hi I want to implement jwt login method in django rest framework.

Below are the libraries I use.

asgiref 3.7.2
Django 5.0
django-debug-toolbar 4.2.0
djangorestframework 3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt 5.3.1
pip 23.3.1
PyJWT 2.8.0
pytz 2023.3.post1
setuptools 68.2.2
sqlparse 0.4.4

Python Version is 3.11.6

Below are the settings I made.

*settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    ...

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'debug_toolbar',

    ...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

REST_USE_JWT = True

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

User Model Custom

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, **kwargs):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        superuser = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        
        superuser.is_staff = True
        superuser.is_superuser = True
        superuser.is_active = True
        
        superuser.save(using=self._db)
        return superuser
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from accounts.managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # 헬퍼 클래스 사용
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

Signup, Login

```
class RegisterAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            
            token = TokenObtainPairSerializer.get_token(user)
            refresh_token = str(token)
            access_token = str(token.access_token)
            res = Response(
                {
                    "user": serializer.data,
                    "message": "register successs",
                },
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
            
            return res
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        user = authenticate(
            username=request.data.get("username"),
            password=request.data.get("password"),
        )

        if user is not None:
            serializer = UserSerializer(user)

            token = TokenObtainPairSerializer.get_token(user)
            refresh_token = str(token)
            access_token = str(token.access_token)
            res = Response(
                {
                    "user": serializer.data,
                    "message": "login success",
                    "token": {
                        "access": access_token,
                        "refresh": refresh_token,
                    },
                },
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )

            # res.set_cookie("access", access_token, httponly=True)
            # res.set_cookie("refresh", refresh_token, httponly=True)
            return res
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

A token is issued through the login API and the token is used as the bearer token value of postman.

However, when I access the following API, it keeps saying that the Token has expired.

```
class BalanceAPI(APIView):

    permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)

    ...
```

Below is the error message displayed.

```
{
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I use Token normally?

Comment: can you please show me the simpleJWT settings that you define in your settings.py file.

Comment: @TanveerAhmad Hi, Tanveer. A section defining settings has been added to the text. Please check the code box at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. But i m unable to get any issue from your code.
This is how i do when i create user. when creating User model i create a function related to JWT.
When user create i call that function with this user like this. For example:

```
    def generate_jwt_token(self):
    """Generate a JWT token for the user."""
    token_payload = {
        'user_id': str(self.id),
        'email': self.email,
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=60),  # Token expiration time
    }
    token = jwt.encode(token_payload, secret_env['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256')
    return token

    user = CoreUser.objects.get(email=data['email'])
    user.generate_jwt_token()
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it!